# How can I remove quotes, commas and brackets from lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to remove the quotes, commas and brackets from lists in Python. I am new to programming and don't get it.

```
import itertools
l = ['x', 'o']
card = list(itertools.product(l, repeat= 2))
print(*card, sep = "\n")

#output
('x', 'x')
('x', 'o')
('o', 'x')
('o', 'o')
```

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Eva, if you find an answer that solves your problem, please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by iterating through each item in the list and printing it. Like this -

```
import itertools
l = ['x', 'o']
card = list(itertools.product(l, repeat= 2))
for item in card:
    print(*item, end="\n")
```

Output -

```
x x 
x o 
o x 
o o
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `card` variable is a nested list. To get a smoother looking output of lists (and other iterables), join each item with a separator, e.g. a single space:

```py
for item in card:
    print(' '.join(item))
```

output:

```
x x
x o
o x
o o
```

Comment: Maybe could I ask for help, how this nested list would look like, if I not use the itertools module?

Comment: The list looks like this: `[('x', 'x'), ('x', 'o'), ('o', 'x'), ('o', 'o')]`. itertools is just a convenient way to to combine the two inputs x and o. You could create it manually too.

Comment: I am sorry, I think I was expressing myself incorrectly. I was thinking about how the code would like, if I use a nested for loop instead of itertools. Just for my understanding and learning. I am really at the beginning of programming.

Comment: you could have a nested for loop or use a list comprehension; `card = [(first, second) for first in l for second in l]`

Comment: I understand, Thank you!

Comment: (`card = list(itertools.product(l, repeat= 6))`)Can anyone help how this would be written in a nested foor loop instead of using itertools? I know, this might make no sense, but I would like to understand. Thank you!

Comment: Please ask a new question for that